# I can't filter based on a field in one-to-one field reference to another model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want the to be able to filter on email in `Student`. 
like when I do this:  `Student.objects.get(email="k@gmail.com")`

The row where the student has email="k@gmail.com" where be returned.

I've tried using the below version and that gave me this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'kkk@gmail.com'

I have also tried to print out type:

views.py

```py
for l in ll:
        print(type(l.email.email)). # got <class 'str'>
        print(type(l.language_to_learn))

print(type(l.email)) # got <class 'users.models.CustomUser'>


def profile_list(request):
    profile=Student.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    return render(request,'view_profile.html',{'profile':profile})
```

models.py

```py
class Student(models.Model):
          email=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
      language_to_learn=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=Language_Choices,default='English',)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['language_to_learn',]

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address' ,unique=True,blank=False, null=False) 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    fullname=models.CharField('Full name',max_length=50,null=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # removes email from REQUIRED_FIELDS
    objects = UserManager()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should change the models.py `email` field as `user` instead of `email` to avoid confusion.

```
class Student(models.Model):      
  user=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

and then query like.

```
profile=Student.objects.get(user__email=request.user.email)
```

> If you **don't want to change the field name**. Then you should do like below coz email is a field of related OneToOneField of CustomUser.

```
profile=Student.objects.get(email__email=request.user.email)
```

Comment: @kokoniky, You can select the answer if it has resolved your query. Thanks